# T-SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table its name - UserData and its contain one column name -
   UserInfo.

UserInfo column contains following values likes

demo.acc.in

swiss.com.au

austa.edu.co

I want to extract the following information from it...

```
Output   Output    

 acc       in
 com       au
 edu       co
```

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: You've **just asked** this very same question only **6 hours ago** - please **DO NOT** repost the same question over and over and over again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`parsename()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx) for this example.

```
select parsename(UserInfo,2), parsename(UserInfo,1)
```

Note that `parsename()` reads from right to left, so the 1st element is the last element when reading from left to right.

rextester: http://rextester.com/FUGXQ46552

```
create table t (UserInfo varchar(32))
insert into t values 
 ('demo.acc.in')
,('swiss.com.au')
,('austa.edu.co')
,('sqlzim.austa.edu.co')

select 
    p1=parsename(UserInfo,1)
  , p2=parsename(UserInfo,2)
  , p3=parsename(UserInfo,3)
  , p4=parsename(UserInfo,4)
from t

+----+-----+-------+--------+
| p1 | p2  |  p3   |   p4   |
+----+-----+-------+--------+
| in | acc | demo  | NULL   |
| au | com | swiss | NULL   |
| co | edu | austa | NULL   |
| co | edu | austa | sqlzim |
+----+-----+-------+--------+
```